# The correct way to use PHP's mysql_connect functionality?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, database

I am creating a registration form that will be using JQuerys AJAX feature, I am sending the data from the form to a PHP script.

Below is the JS code that sends the data to a script and then attaches any feedback to a div, this means that a page doesn't have to be refreshed:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "public/includes/userCreate.php",
    type: "POST",     
    data: 
    { 
        username: user_username, 
        forename: user_forename,
        surname: user_surname,
        email: user_email01,
        password: user_password01
    }, 
    success: function(html) 
    {             
        $('#web_Content').html(html);
    }      
});
```

I can then use the following code that attaches the echo contents into the web_Content div:

```
<?php
    $new_Username = $_POST['username'];
    $new_Forename = $_POST['forename'];
    $new_Surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $new_Email = $_POST['email'];
    $new_Password = $_POST['password'];

    echo "Username is: " . $new_Username;
    echo "Forename is: " . $new_Forename;
    echo "Surname is: " . $new_Surname;
    echo "Email is: " . $new_Email;
    echo "Password is: " . $new_Password;   
?>
```

I would like to insert the values into a database.  I will first test the MySQL functionality with the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","mypass");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (user_Username, user_Email, user_Password) VALUES ('TestMan', 'tom@mail.com', 'qwerty' ) ");
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't seem to work", what exactly do you mean? Have you tried loading the URL you're calling in your ajax call directly in the browser? Have you tried putting an error handler into your ajax to see if it gets triggered?

Comment: Are the columns in the `users` table named `user_Username`, `user_Email`, and `user_Password`? Does the same SQL work in the MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: Try putting that on a separate page, and access it directly. Do you get any errors?

Comment: For the record, never store a password as plaintext in the db. Use some sort of one-way encryption.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: As noted, we'll need to know what is happening when you say "it doesn't work." Do you have phpmyadmin installed too? Does that let you login and run queries?

Comment: Don't use `root` as your database account, even if you're just playing around. Create an account solely for your scripts to use, with limited privileges. insert/update/delete/select is usually enough for most anything you'd be doing in a web-facing script.

Answer (score 3):

- [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)
- [mysql_select_db](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)
- [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

All return false on failure. You should be checking return values, and if false is returned check [mysql_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).

There are so many possible causes, do you have all error reporting turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Check it like this:

```
$host = "localhost";
$login = "root";
$pwd = "mypass";

$conn = mysql_connect($host,$login,$pwd);
if (!Sconn) die("Server not found");

$db = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
if (!Sdb) die("Database not found");

$sql = "INSERT INTO ..."; // full query omitted 
echo("Sending query://$sql//"); // The slashes are to see exactly the query

$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$query) die("SQL error");
```

Then act according to the error messages you get.